# Can I make an Angular directive to match a CSS selector (not just tag name)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I can define a directive that affects all `<a>` elements in a document like so:

```
myApp.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // Some custom logic to apply to all <a> elements
    }
  };
});
```

Can I do the same, but for elements matching a given CSS selector? Like this?

```
myApp.directive('a[href^="mailto:"]', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // Some custom logic to apply to all <a> elements
      // w/ a href attribute starting in "mailto:"
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I realize that if the answer is "no", there is a clear workaround: to simply check the element within the `link` function and exit if it doesn't match whatever selector I'm looking for. Question still stands!

Comment: I fear the answer is no and you will have to use that work around.  You may want to post something on Angular's github as a feature request.

Comment: I also suspect it's a no. However, the work around I would do is a bit different if possible. I would not have an element directive on 'a', but an attribute directive on a custom 'my-href' attribute. Or maybe an attribute directive `href` if you're not able to change the template for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

No.

When you register directive under a specific name angular puts directive into directive cache under the new name or pushes it to the list of already existing directives under the specified name.

After that, angular searches dom through to find correspondence between your directive and (tagName|attrName|className|commentName) and when found angular calls compile function of each directive in the list and passes the found (element, attrs) as arguments into compile function.

So in your case `a[href^="mailto:"]` will be searched as is `'<a[href^="mailto:"]></a[href^="mailto:"]>'` which is obviously inexistent, and the same for attribute, class and comment.

In your case the most sane solution is:

```
myApp.directive('a', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (attrs.href.indexOf('mailto:') !== 0) { return; }
        // Some custom logic to apply to all a[href^="mailto:"] elements
    }
  };
});
```